# Unable to put payload in backout queue from Datapower

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-datapower

I have configured MQ Front side handler and trying to put message in backout queue dynamically using XSLT in Datapower. I have added this stylesheet in Error rule. In my XSL I have written as below for routing:

`<dp:url-open target="{$BackoutQ"} http-headers="$headers response="responsecode-ignore" timeout="10" data-type="xml"> <xsl:copy-of select="dp:request-header(MQMD')"/> </dp:url-open>`

in request queue I have put message "BackoutTest". It's reaching to the backout Queue but there's no payload in it. How to inject backout count header dynamically and put the payload in backout Queue ?

Answer (score 0):

On the MQ queue manager object you can configure automatic backout, so I don't see why you are trying to do it manually.

Point 5/b from the link below:

> Enable the Automatic backout property to back out of poison messages automatically.
> A poison message is any message that the receiving application does not know how to process. Usually an application rolls back this message, which leaves the message on the input queue but increases the MQMD.Backoutcount backout count. As the local queue manager continues to attempt to retrieve the message, the backout count continues to increase. When the backout count reaches the backout threshold, the local queue manager moves the message to the backout queue.
> When disabled, the request rule must use a custom stylesheet to reroute poison messages.

[DataPower documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/datapower-gateway/10.5.0?topic=integration-configuring-mq-queue-manager)